# Arduino Liquid Crystal Display not printing

Tags: arduino, lcd

I am attempting to use the liquid crystal display of an Arduino Uno for a school project. I followed the instructions on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld exactly as it is stated and it does not print the text.
The backlight is functioning properly and the contrast is adjusting with the potentiometer, but no text comes out.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
    // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    // Print a message to the LCD.
    lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
    // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
    // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    // print the number of seconds since reset:
    lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
}
```

[image]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the image you linked it looks like the display isn't properly connected: you should solder a pin header to it first.

See the part near the red arrow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIDuK.jpg

Comment: It isn’t soldered. Is there no way for it to work otherwise?